# how to scale line width depending on screen size in JSXGraph

Tags: jsxgraph

Probably this has been asked and answered before, but I could not find the answer either here or in the JSXgraph reference.

Is there a way to dynamically change the stroke width of a line when the size of the board (on the screen) is changing?
Ideally I would like to set a percentage value, but I am not sure if this is possible, since (as far as I understand) the values for possible stroke widths are integers.

What I am looking for is a solution that sets different stroke width values when the screen size on the viewing device is changing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal way to make the scale width dependent on the width of the JSXGraph board:

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
    boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5], axis:true
});

var sizeFunc = () => board.canvasWidth / 200;
var line = board.create('line', [[-3,-1], [2, 3]], {strokeWidth: sizeFunc});
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/art5g2u7/. Since some years, stroke widths can be given as arbitrary floating point numbers. Only early IE versions needed integer numbers (as far as I remember).

**Update**, addressing the follow-up questions by Ferenc Beleznay:

If different scale factors for different elements are needed, be aware that the JSXGraph attribute's value still has to be a function. In the
jsfiddle in the comment the code looks like this:

```
var sizeFunc = (scale) => board.canvasWidth / scale;    
var resetLogo1a = board.create('arc', 
       [[3,-6], [3,-5.5], [3.5,-6]],
       {highlight: false, ...,
        center:{visible:false}, 
        strokeWidth: sizeFunc(100)
       });
```

That is, the function `sizeFunc` is evaluated once when the arc element is created and returns a number. This number will then become the (fixed) stroke width of that element. However, what is needed in this situation is a function, i.e. `sizeFunc` has to return a function, like this:

```
var sizeFunc = function(scale) { return () => board.canvasWidth / scale; };    
var resetLogo1a = board.create('arc', 
       [[3,-6], [3,-5.5], [3.5,-6]],
       {highlight: false, ...,
        center:{visible:false}, 
        strokeWidth: sizeFunc(100)
       });
```

Now, the value of the attribute `strokeWidth` is a function. See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/qyh1oz3m/.

Comment: Perfect! For some reason the jsfiddle does not work for me, but I could implement your code and it does what I need.

Comment: Just one more question. I applied this function to set the width of the border of a rectangle, an arc, a functiongraph and an arrow (and arrowhead). It works nicely when the graph is drawn, and the border of the rectangle updates nicely when the size of the window is changing. However, the width of the arc, the functiongraph and the arrowhead does not update. I guess, I need to call board.update() at some point, but I do not know when. What kind of event handler do I need for this?

Comment: Can you supply a jsfiddle, please?

Comment: Here is a link to a jsfiddle with a code I am trying to run. https://jsfiddle.net/q85zdcn1/ (although, as with your jsfiddle, it does not seem to work, I cannot see anything in the output). I used a slightly modified sizeFunc (with a scale variable to use different scale to different objects). On the copy I am running locally the border of the rectangle changes when I resize the window, but the strokewidth of the arc and the size of the arrowhead does not.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason the sizeFunc is missing from the previous link, here is the edited jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hcvypfen/